# AppXtender WebService URL or Catalogue of Services

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Any ideas on how we can get the AppXtender WebService URL's? Or a catalogue of Services installed under AppXtender and their URL's?

Thank You,
Neil

Answer (score 0):

If you log into your server you will see a number of options listed under ApplicationXtender Desktop:

[image: ApplicationXtender 1]

If you click on the Web Services Test Console it will open up a little tool that may be what you're looking for:

[image]

In my case I had to replace "localhost" with my actual dev server name.

This may or may not be what you're looking for.